# Post to Twitter from a web client after @Anywhere is sunsetted

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

My current web app uses the @Anywhere API to allow users to post messages to Twitter(which are formatted and have a hash tag appended to them)  Works pretty well with no intervention necessary on the server-side, but it seems Twitter is deprecating the @Anywhere API and their OAuth 1 replacement does not seem to replace much of the functionality of @Anywhere

With the new API, is it possible to post to a user's timeline using a 100% client-side flow like we are currently doing with @Anywhere or Twitter boxes?  If so, how can I do it?

For performance and implementation reasons, I would rather not post from the server if at all possible.